# How to use PayPal permission token to obtain transaction information

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

PayPal API seems to be a disaster, but I'm battling through...

So far I have been able to generate a token and verification code from https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp

The token and verification are authorised to use the TRANSACTION_SEARCH, TRANSACTION_DETAILS and ACCOUNT_BALANCE scopes.

But I can't find anywhere how to actually get transaction details or balances using the token and verification code.

My current code that is working uses the NVP API, but this has been validated by manually granting permissions from within PayPal. I can't see how to do this using the token and verify code.

My current code (if it helps) which is working well, but without using the token and verification:

```
$vars['USER'] = $api_username;
$vars['PWD'] = $api_password;
$vars['SIGNATURE'] = $api_signature;
$vars['STARTDATE'] = '2016-11-30T00:00:00Z;
$vars['SUBJECT'] = 'my@paypalemail.com';
$vars['METHOD'] = 'GetBalance';

$vars = http_build_query($vars);

$curl = curl_init('https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $vars);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

How do I convert this to use my App ID, token and verify_code generated by PayPal Permissions API?

Thanks!